# Хотя и обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли обособлять "хотя и" при присоединении однородного члена предложения? Например в предложении: "*Читал похожие, **хотя и** не равноценные (,) записи*". В Национальном корпусе встретила и вариант без обособления и с обособлением.
1) *Эти шаги могут быть реализованы в различном, **хотя и** не в произвольном порядке, повторяться и выполняться с различных узлов АС*.
2) "*Все наши участки вместе с сообществом растений - объекты живые, развивающиеся по своим законам, в которых есть и конкурентная борьба, и строгие предпочтения, и железная, **хотя и** не всегда понятная человеку непосвящённому, логика*".

Answer (score 1):

**Возможны оба варианта:**

(1) **Однородные члены** с дополнительным значением: сопоставление и уступка: Читал похожие, хотя и не равноценные записи.

(2) Вариант с обособлением ― это **присоединительный член** предложения с добавочным значением (авторский выбор): ....хотя и не всегда понятная человеку непосвящённому, логика". Возможно, обособление связано с распространенностью второго определения.